# Angular foreach wants to wait until response for single call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have thousands of records in my array. I wish to perform  some function on each element of my array. Though my functions works fine, but I want to delay the call of next item until first is parsed properly. I don't have relevancy of return either it is true or not. I just wish to delay loop until single item is parsed.

I tried.

```
 $scope.getInfo = function (funcName) {

            $http.get(Youtube.getDetails(funcName)).success(function (data, status, headers, config) { // this callback will be called asynchronously when the response is available
                if (!angular.isUndefinedOrNull(data.nextPageToken)) {
                    $scope.form.playlistToken = data.nextPageToken;
                } else {
                    $scope.form.playlistToken = "";
                    $scope.form.playlistUrl = "";
                }
                if (data.items.length > 0) {
                    angular.forEach(data.items, function (value, key) {
                        var youTubeData = Youtube.parseVideoDetail(value);
                        if (!angular.isUndefinedOrNull(youTubeData.videoId)) {
                            Video.find({filter: {where: {videoId: youTubeData.videoId}}}).$promise.then(function (data) {
                                if (data.length == 0) {
                                    Video.create(youTubeData).$promise.then(function (value, responseHeader) {
                                        $scope.items.splice(0, 0, youTubeData);
                                        youTubeData = {};
 //                                       $scope.form.url = "";
                                        toastr.success("Record saved successfully", "Success");
                                    }, function (reason) {
                                        toastr.error("Video can't be saved. Please check.", "Error");
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    duplicate.push(youTubeData.videoId);
                                    toastr.error("Video already exist with id - " + youTubeData.videoId, "Error");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    failed.push(funcName.values.id);
                    toastr.warning("No details found !!", "Warning");
                }
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs or server returns response with an error status.
                toastr.error("Youtube API failed to fetch data.", "Error");
            });
        }


   $scope.saveVideo = function () {
     //       var videoId = Youtube.getYoutubeParser($scope.form.url);
            var arrVid = []; // this is actually an array of 2K+ items.
            angular.forEach(arrVid, function (value, key) {
                var videoId = value.replace("?v=", "");
                Youtube.params.videoInfo.values.id = videoId;
                $scope.getInfo(Youtube.params.videoInfo);
            });
            console.log("Failed Videos" + JSON.stringify(failed));
            console.log("Duplicate Videos" + JSON.stringify(duplicate));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use foreach for your scenario. you can utilize **$timeout or $interval** of angularjs. both of them perform start and stop operations with some interval.

Comment: But I wish to perform next iteration on completion of current iteration.